# try to find count numbers at string

Tags: java, android

```
String at = "123123";
        for (int i = 0; i <at.length() ; i++) {
            if (at.charAt(i)==1){
                int count=0;
                count++;
            }
        }
```

Want 1 appears 2 times. Where my fail. Thanks.

Comment: `int count=0;` should be placed outside the for loop.

Comment: Your problem is here `at.charAt(i)==1`. You shouldn't compare a char with an int like that. Either use `at.charAt(i)=='1'` or `at.charAt(i)==49`. And what Tunaki said :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String at = "123123";
int count = 0; // Move out
for (int i = 0; i < at.length(); i++) {
  if (at.charAt(i) == '1'){ // Compare with the char '1'
    count++;
  }
}
// count is 2 here.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String at = "123123";
    int count = 0;//outside the loop
    int oneDigitCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < at.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(at.charAt(i))) {//digit count
            count++;
        }
        if(at.charAt(i)=='1'){//count ones in string
            oneDigitCount++; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: And? ... is your answer "6" (which wouldn't be correct), or "1"?

Comment: You are counting the number of digits, not '1' occurrences.

Comment: I thought you wanted to count the digits in a string. Sorry

Comment: To compare for a specific digit just compare == 'digit' example: =='1'